# I want to find fingerprint interface bound by adb

Tags: adb

I want to know the specific location on a smartphone where a white interface resembling a fingerprint appears, using adb.

I found many others by google but i can't find solition.

is there any adb command that i find fingerprint location at devices?

example:
Top left corner : 100, 120
width and height : 50, 50

Comment: Add a screenshot to understand what you are talking about

Comment: If I understand it correctly this question is about fingerprint sensors that are not on the backside of the device but underneath the display. mobbbbb tries to find out via adb at which screen position such a fingerprint sensor is located in each device /thus which display region is not usable by an app when the fingerprint sensor is activated.